# Error with using json classes from within kotlin REPL and scratch files

Tags: android, json, kotlin, kotlinc

I'm working on an Android project that needs to process json data retrieved from a web API. From within the project I successfully used the classes `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` (package `org.json`) without any problems.

Always running compiling, running and navigating the app each time I want to try some json processing is annoying, so I decided to give scratch files a try.

My scratch file looks like this:

```
import org.json.JSONObject

val jsonObject = JSONObject(
    """
    {
      "data": [
        ...
      ]
    }
    """
)

println(jsonObject["data"])
```

When I try to run the file, I get an error stating that the import wasn't successful:

```
error: unresolved reference: json (scratch.kts:1:12)
error: unresolved reference: JSONObject (scratch.kts:3:18)
scratch.kts:1:12: error: unresolved reference: json
import org.json.JSONObject
           ^
scratch.kts:3:18: error: unresolved reference: JSONObject
val jsonObject = JSONObject(
                 ^

Process finished with exit code 1
```

From my understanding this is because the `org.json` classes are now part of Android, and the Android framework isn't available from a scratch file. But how can I solve this? Shouldn't I be able to import the `org.json` package apart from the Android framework somehow?

Comment: did you figure this out? I am seeing same problem when I try to use coroutines in scratch file

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `import android.*` in your scratch file, you have to connect to the classpath of your Android-module (see example-screenshot below). Anyhow, this comes with the drawback that you have to have a runnable project.

[image: classpath-example]

Comment: Great, thank you very much! I've never noticed that dropdown.